# selenium grid + java + testNG + launch browser with URL

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I am new to to this "selenium grid + testNG" and was not able to find a way to solve it. Hopw somw one will help mw with this.

Requirement: Wanted to launch 100 browsers in 10 VM (10 browsers for each VM) and open up a page. So used the following code to launch it.

java class:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class LaunchBrowser {
    public String hubHost;
    public int hubPort;
    public String presentationServerUrl;
    public String canvasID;
    private Selenium selenium = null;
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp(ITestContext context) {
        System.out.println("@BeforeSuite called................");

        hubHost = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("hubHost");
        hubPort = Integer.parseInt(context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("hubPort"));
        presentationServerUrl =       context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("presentationServerUrl");
        canvasID = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("canvasID");

        System.out.println("hubHost: " + hubHost + " ,hubPort: " + hubPort+ "  ,presentationServerUrl: " + presentationServerUrl    + " ,canvasID: " + canvasID);
    }

    @Test(invocationCount = 3)
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void startBrowser(String browser) {

        System.out.println("Browser====>>>"+ browser);

        selenium = new DefaultSelenium(hubHost, hubPort, "*"+browser, presentationServerUrl);
        selenium.start();
        selenium.open(presentationServerUrl);
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.type("id=usernameId", "admin");
        selenium.type("id=passwordId", "aspect@123");
        selenium.click("id=submitId");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("id=btnRPToggleId");
        selenium.click("id=btnSearchRBId");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        selenium.click("id="+canvasID);

    }
}
```

TestNG.xml

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
    <parameter name="hubHost" value="localhost" />
    <parameter name="hubPort" value="4444" />
    <parameter name="presentationServerUrl" value="http://10.153.22.64:11090" />
    <parameter name="canvasID" value="btnSPOepnDashBoard663033f0-2913-11e4-9c0f-a95eb7e2fcf7" />

    <test name="FireFox Test">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
       <classes>
           <class name="com.aspect.testsLaunchBrowser" />
       </classes>
   </test>

</suite>
```

Problem :When I execute the testNG file browser gets launched and the particular page gets opened. But after some time the browser gets killed which in my case it should not happen.

The following is what I am getting in my node console after the above test got executed.

```
03:20:35.898 INFO - Killing Firefox...
03:20:36.195 INFO - Got result: OK on session dad4ea094a0b4763b0c0d62541ce511f
```

I am searching for a way to get this working but not finding a solution.

Comment: When you say, "after some time", how long is it? You have a pointless 20-second wait; have you tried changing it?

Comment: yes after 20 seconds the browser gets killed. Is it a default behaviour of TestNG test function? I believe after the test case is successful then the browser gets killed. My requirement is to make the browser stay open for long.

Comment: So, in other words, your test is doing **exactly** what you are telling it to do: do some stuff, wait 20 seconds, click a button and then you are done. When the test is done, there is no more use for the browser. In fact, the log message says everything is OK.

Comment: Yes it is right. But I wanted it to stay opened so there is load on my server. It is basically for server load test.

Comment: Any suggestion on this issue would be great help for me.

Comment: Right now, your code doesn't show anything after `startBrowser`. If you don't have any code executing after it, `selenium`, the web browser goes out of scope and the web driver shuts down.

Comment: Bob I got the flow thanks for the reply. I just want to know that if we can leave the browser untouched after startbrowser. My intention to load my web server with 100 client browsers.

Comment: Selenium may not be the best tool for that job. Using JMeter or a similar load testing tool would allow you to fire up as many browsers as you need, spreading them across multiple machines, etc.